# How to use $_GET function Wordpress backend

Tags: php, plugin-development, permalinks, urls

I use Plugin Boilerplate for my project. I searched the internet and read all the questions but I couldn’t find what I need. I also read the WordPress Codex. I think I couldn’t get the idea.

I have two columns on my page. Col1 and Col2

```
Inside col1: wp_list_table
Inside col2: empty
```

Page address: `admin.php?page=company#home`

When I clicked the Add New button on `wp_list_table`, the address bar shows `admin.php?page=company#home&action=new`

I want to get the action value from the url. I tried the code below:

```
function addnew_query_vars($vars) {
 $vars[] = 'action';
 return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter');

echo $value = get_query_var('action'); // Nothing happens
```

How I can get action value? If I can get the value, I’ll show a form inside the col2 or using a switch statement for other situations.

---

**UPDATE** 1.1.0

**Using get_current_screen**

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php');                     
$screen = get_current_screen();
echo $screen->action; // Null
```

I'm using query monitor plugin. I looked Admin Screen status get_current_screen() action is empty. So I need to go back.

In the my WP_List_Table header code, my **Add New** button code is like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=company#home&action=new' );?>">
php _e( 'Add New', 'ironhead' )
</a>
```

I think this code block doesn't post the action. There is set_current_screen() command. But I don't solve how to set Admin Screen action attribute. IF I can use it, I can use get_current_screen(). Anyone help me?

**ALL CODE**

**TAB PANE**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills tab-pane" id="myTab" role="tablist">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Company</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" id="facility-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#facility"  role="tab" aria-controls="facility" aria-selected="false">Facility</a>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

**TAB CONTENT**

```
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<?php
function wp_get_all_company( $args = array() ) {
global $wpdb;

$defaults = array(
'number'     => 20,
'offset'     => 0,
'orderby'    => 'ID',
'order'      => 'ASC',
);

$args      = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
$cache_key = 'company-all';
$items     = wp_cache_get( $cache_key, 'ironhead' );

if ( false === $items ) {
$items = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'ih_company ORDER BY ' . $args['orderby'] .' ' . $args['order'] .' LIMIT ' . $args['offset'] . ', ' . $args['number'] );

wp_cache_set( $cache_key, $items, 'ironhead' );
}

return $items;
}

function wp_get_company_count() {
global $wpdb;

return (int) $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'ih_company' );
}

function wp_get_firma( $id = 0 ) {
global $wpdb;

return $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'ih_company WHERE ID = %d', $id ) );
} ?>

<h4><?php _e( 'Company List', 'ironhead' ); ?> <a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=company#home&action=new' ); ?>" class="add-new-h2"><?php _e( 'Add New', 'ironhead' ); ?></a></h4>

<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="ttest_list_table">

<?php
$list_table = new Company_List_Table();
$list_table->prepare_items();
$list_table->search_box( 'search', 'search_id' );
$list_table->display();
?>
</form>
</div>
<div class="col">

// action=new (or action=something) if or switch statement will be here.

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the `#home` coming from? Are you adding that to the page url? IIRC, Anything that comes after the `#` is not sent to the server.

Comment: Hi @czerspalace My active tab name is "home". col1 and col2 is inside it.

Comment: Are you adding the active tab name yourself? You would need to change the Add New to `admin.php?action=new&page=company#home`

Comment: I wanna do everything in one page. So, I used bootstrap tabs.

Comment: The `#` is causing the action to not go to the server. So the `#home` needs to be at the end of the query string, so like `admin.php?action=new&page=company#home` or `admin.php?page=company&action=new#home`. Can you post code of the how the "Add New" button is generated?

Comment: I tried to put # at end of the address. Nothing has changed. I used WP List Generator [link](http://projects.tareq.co/wp-generator/list-table.php) and my page slug is admin.php?page=company#home (I'll put the all code into the question.)

Comment: What if you change `echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=company#home&action=new' )` to `echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=company&action=new#home' )`

Comment: Nothing. :( @czerspalace

Comment: It looks like the code still has `#` before `action=new`

Comment: Yes @czerspalace . I decided I’ll coding with Codestar framework. I have nothing and didn’t solve the problem. If there is not exact answer, I’ll close the question. 

Answer (score 0):

Working in the admin is quite a bit different from the front-end of a WordPress site. Most of the documentation you'll find online deals solely with the front-end. That can be frustrating when looking for something that should be simple and straightforward.

In this case, I think you would use [`get_current_screen()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen). This returns the screen's ID, action, base, and other features of the admin page.

From the codex on `get_current_screen()`:

> This function returns an object that includes the screen’s ID, base,
> post type, and taxonomy, among other data points

This doesn't work everywhere in the admin, so make sure you read the restrictions.

Comment: @mikengarrent I noticed that get_current_screen() is best solution. Thanks. I updated my question. You can see the new situation. Can I get a new suggestion?

Comment: Hi @MikeNGarrett, I red all stack exchange questions and codex. I didn't solve to use set_current_screen() function. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it's true or false, there is a solution with form element and old PHP knowledge :)

**FORM**

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="admin.php?page=company#home">
<h4><?php _e( 'Firma Listesi', 'ironhead' ); ?>
<input id="action" name="action" hidden="" type="text" value="new">
<button id="new" name="action_new" class="add-new-h2"><?php _e( 'Add New', 'ironhead' ); ?></button></h4>
</form>
```

**POST**

```
echo @$_POST['action'];
```

Is there any true method?

Answer (score 0):

@Pecado yes, $_POST['action'] will work. I have created a page in admin section and I've used form to submit and retrieving form field on $_POST

Comment: Yes, It's workin but not for every links on WP_List_Table. For example, company views link is the same pattern: admin.php?page=company#home&action=view&id=1. And this solution isn't real solution after all. Because, I can't handle all links in WP_List_Table. :(